# How To Exclude Queries Returned From mysqldumpslow Command

Tags: mysql, performance, regex, slow-log

I would like to ignore queries in the mysql-slow log that originate from running the command [`mysqldumpslow`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html) by using `SQL_NO_CACHE` as the trigger word.

My experience using regex are limited at best and I'm unable to find any examples in the docs.

I've tried a few variations of the following:

```
mysqlslowdump -g '!(SQL_NO_CACHE)' /path/to/my/log
mysqlslowdump -g '^!(SQL_NO_CACHE)$' /path/to/my/log
```

... but always get back:

> ```
> Died at /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow line 162
> ```

What is wrong in my regex?

Comment: Suggest switching to pt-query-digest.  It may not do what you are asking for, but it may have better output in general.

Comment: heh... it looks like it would actually be something along the lines of `-g '(?{{ undef $_ if \/SQL_NO_CACHE\/ }})'` ... now, I'm curious.  Negative matching doesn't seem to be natively supported, but it "should" be possible (famous last words).

Comment: I believe the question is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444018/died-at-usr-bin-mysqldumpslow-line-162

Answer (score 1):

OK - you should check out the page [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/query-cache-in-select.html),

```
    (Due to a limitation in the parser, a space character must precede 
and follow the SQL_NO_CACHE keyword; a nonspace such as a newline 
causes the server to check the query cache to see whether 
the result is already cached.)
```

Now, it is possible that the syntax that you are using doesn't correspond to the bit about "newlines" above - I'm not sure. Maybe you could try running your queries directly from the command line?

[EDIT] in response to OP's comment.

```
mysqlslowdump -g '!(SQL_NO_CACHE)' /path/to/my/log
mysqlslowdump -g '^!(SQL_NO_CACHE)$' /path/to/my/log
```

I've never come across this problem, but is it possible that rewriting your code with spaces surrounding "SQL_NO_CACHE" could have some effect?

Comment: Interesting tidbit, but I don't think it's applicable - or controllable.  The queries are generated from a backup using mysqldump.  The log file also is not displaying any indication that a newline is present (as is for other, non-targeted, queries.

Comment: The question is about using an option in mysqlslowdump. The answer is about how MySQL executes some queries. Useful, but unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not reproduce

> Died at /usr/bin/mysqldumpslow line 162

but to answer

> I would like to ignore queries in the mysql-slow log that originate
> from running the command mysqldumpslow by using SQL_NO_CACHE as the
> trigger word.

this works for me:

```
mysqldumpslow -g '^(?!.*SQL_NO_CACHE)'
```